# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/etc/letsencrypt/live/awiclass.monoame.com/privkey.pem' at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:646:18)

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I don't know why can't I let my API listen on 4000,and my server also doesn't work , and it always says can't not find this "/etc/letsencrypt/live/awiclass.monoame.com/privkey.pem " file !!!!!! and the result should be server socket 4040 , api 4000. API listen on 4000

```
write on the command line:

npm i socket.io express -s
var fs = require('fs')
//https的一些設定
var options = {
key: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/awiclass.monoame.com/privkey.pem'),
cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/awiclass.monoame.com/fullchain.pem')
}

//https & socket port
var https = require('https').createServer(options);
https.listen(4040)
var io = require('socket.io')(https);

console.log("Server socket 4040 , api 4000")

//api port
var app = require('express')();
var port = 4000;
app.listen(port, function(){
console.log('API listening on *:' + port);
});


var messages = [];

//用api方式取得
app.get('/api/messages',function(req,res){
res.send(messages);
})

io.on('connection', function(socket){
//初始化...
console.log("A user connected.");
io.emit("allMessage",messages);

socket.on('sendMessage',function(obj){
//get all message!
messages.push(obj);
console.log( obj.message + " - " + obj.name )
io.emit('newMessage', obj);
})
})


Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
'/etc/letsencrypt/live/awiclass.monoame.com/privkey.pem'
at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:646:18)
at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:551:33)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/jennielin/index11.js:3:11)
at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:188:16)
```

Comment: What is your question? Can you show, as formatted text in the question, what you are trying to do, what you have tried, and what results you get? [Edit] the question and show what errors you get.

Answer (score 0):

Your program tried to look for a private key file (`privkey.pem`) in the `/etc/letsencrypt/live/awiclass.monoame.com` directory. It could not find the file, and since there was no error handling done in the case that the file isn't found, it crashed.

You can fix this by adding a `privkey.pem` file to that directory.